# Fetching network time from simcon 800c gsm module

Tags: at-commands

Is there any way to fetch the current time from the 800c GSM module. I tried the following commands:

```
AT+CENG=2
AT+CLTS=1 
AT+CCLK?
```

Output:

```
+ceng:"4/01/01,00:35:+22
```

Not getting the updated date and time from network.

Comment: Does the module respond with `OK` after `AT+CLTS=1` ?

Comment: Not all networks send a time signal. AT+CCLK? gives you the module's RTC time.

Comment: @BenceKaulics yes it responded with ok.then after executing the next instruction it is responding me the same string as shown above .only the GSM time is correct `+22`.as here in india standard time is GMT+5:30 so that make equal to 22 Quaters . @pjc50 20 i tried the same with three service providers still same.

Comment: Before blaming the GSM module, check whether your mobile phone is able to pick the time from the cellular network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried the following commands to get the correct time from the network.

```
AT+COPS=2
AT+CLTS=1
AT+COPS=0
AT+CCLK?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
AT+CREG?
AT+CLTS=1
AT+CFUN=0
AT+CFUN=1
AT+CCLK?
```

......Got the time and date perfectly